# fatal error allowed memory size composer

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, composer-php

I am trying to update the lock file using this command `sudo php composer.phar update --lock` but I get the following error 
`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52`
 even if I modified the value of memory_limit to 512M need help

Comment: Make sure you are running the latest version composer (execute `php composer.phar self-update`) and try again with `sudo php -dmemory_limit=-1 composer.phar update --lock`.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this in Windows with:

php -d memory_limit=-1 C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar update

Answer (score 0):

Composer easily uses one gigabyte of memory or more when updating the dependencies, and your error message states an allowed memory limit of about 1 GB - reducing the limit to 512 MB won't really help, you have to increase it beyond 1GB.

Answer (score 0):

php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar install

Answer (score 0):

you can run first composer diagnose, and check what the problem if in any case all is ok. then run

> composer.phar self-update